# How to get the queue not from the context, but through the field?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code that gets the name of the queue from a file, but how can I make it get it by the value passed in the method?

```
public static void initialization(String queue, String ConnectionFactory) throws NamingException, JMSException, IOException {
   InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
   Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue");
   QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
}
```

Here is the file where I get the name of the queue:

```
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory=tcp://localhost:61616
queue.queue=exampleQueue
```

And I need to take it not from a file, but from the method parameters

Comment: Huh?  Then read the queue name from the properties file and pass it in to the context.lookup method.

Comment: I need to dynamically change the value of the queue in Runtime. And I don’t understand how to do this, so I decided to try to do it through the method parameters, but I don’t understand how to substitute this value

Comment: `Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(queue);`

Comment: Well, I will pull from a file, but I need it without the InitialContext class

Comment: you can't bind to a queue dynamically without an initialcontext.  That's how JMS works, so I really don't understand the question, or what you are trying to do.  Best of luck.

Comment: And if you dynamically change the context file, and then change the values ​​in it at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ActiveMQ Artemis you can use the `dynamicQueues` prefix when looking up the queue via JNDI. This is explained in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#destination-jndi) which states:

> It is also possible to look-up JMS destinations which haven't been configured explicitly in the JNDI context environment. This is possible using `dynamicQueues/` or `dynamicTopics/` in the look-up string. For example, if the client wanted to look-up the aforementioned "OrderQueue" it could do so simply by using the string "dynamicQueues/OrderQueue". Note, the text that follows `dynamicQueues/` or `dynamicTopics/` must correspond *exactly* to the name of the destination on the server.

Your code would look something like this:

```java
public static void initialization(String queue, String ConnectionFactory) throws NamingException, JMSException, IOException {
   InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
   Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + queue);
   QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
}
```

Using this method you don't need any queue definitions in your `jndi.properties` file.

Another option would be to simply instantiate the destination using the JMS API. You can do this with the [`createQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-) and [`createTopic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createTopic-java.lang.String-) methods on the JMS `Session`. This is also described in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#directly-instantiating-jms-resources-without-using-jndi).

Comment: And what should be the value of dynamicQueues in the properties file?
dynamicQueues .queue=exampleQueue or ""

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. In short, if you use `dynamicQueues/` you don't need any queue definitions in your `jndi.properties`. That's the _whole point_ of using `dynamicQueues/` in the first place.